# binding of data to dropdownlist getting error of invalid object name in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from state1",con);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds,"state1");------------getting error in this line like invalid object name,satate1
ddlstate.DataSource = ds;
ddlstate.DataTextField = "sname";
ddlstate.DataValueField = "sid" ;
ddlstate.DataBind();
```

Comment: Is it `satate1` or `state1`?

Comment: Can you please share full stacktrace?

Comment: protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
if (IsPostBack == false)
{
bindstatenames();
}
}
public void bindstatenames(){
SqlConnectioncon=newSqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ToString());SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from state1",con);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);ddlstate.DataSource = ds;ddlstate.DataTextField ="sname";ddlstate.DataValueField = "sid" ;ddlstate.DataBind();
ddlstate.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("-Select--","0"));
ddlcity.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select--", "0"));}

Comment: and i created a table with name state1 and having columns of sid and sname

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is "object name,state1" in which case the error is being thrown from your database because it can't find a table or view called state1. Please check that you are connecting to the correct database or if your table is in another schema apart from dbo, that you use the schema qualified name e.g. schemaname.state1

Comment: That's not the point. `SqlDataAdapter.Fill` method creates a new table in `ds` if there is no table called `state1` (or `STATE1`).

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be the problem:

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from state1",con);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds,"state1");
ddlstate.DataSource = ds;//------------------> I think this one is worng. It should be table i.e. ds.Tables[0]/ds.Tables["state1"] if "ds" is not null.
ddlstate.DataTextField = "sname";
ddlstate.DataValueField = "sid" ;
ddlstate.DataBind();
```